# How to implement Pinch Zoom in Picasso library?

Tags: java, android, picasso

I'm using Picasso library in my current project http://square.github.io/picasso/ . Everything is working fine but I just can't figure out how to implement Pinch Zoom for all images that are being loaded from URL. To be honest I don't even know where to place the `onClickListener`.
My application have several fragments and each of them have 2 `Tabs`, first `Tab` has a `ListView` and the second `tab` has some pictures displayed in a `GridView`:

Bmw.java

```
public class Bmw2 extends Fragment {

    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(com.zenyt.R.layout.bmw2, container, false);

        GridView gv = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        gv.setAdapter(new com.zenyt.SampleGridViewAdapter(getActivity()));
        gv.setOnScrollListener(new SampleScrollListener(getActivity()));


        return rootView;
    }
```

SampleGridViewAdapter

```
public final class SampleGridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private final Context context;
    private final List<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();

    public SampleGridViewAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

        // Ensure we get a different ordering of images on each run.
        Collections.addAll(urls, Data.URLS);
        Collections.shuffle(urls);

    }

    @Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        SquaredImageView view = (SquaredImageView) convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = new SquaredImageView(context);
            view.setScaleType(CENTER_CROP);
        }

        // Get the image URL for the current position.
        String url = getItem(position);

        // Trigger the download of the URL asynchronously into the image view.
        Picasso.with(context) //
                .load(url) //
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder) //
                .error(R.drawable.error) //
                .fit() //
                .tag(context) //
                .into(view);

        return view;
    }

    @Override public int getCount() {
        return urls.size();
    }

    @Override public String getItem(int position) {
        return urls.get(position);
    }

    @Override public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

Data.java

```
final class Data {
    static final String BASE = "http://www.hdcarwallpapers.com/walls/";
    static final String BASE2 = "http://www3.cellsea.com//content/wallpaper/";
    static final String EXT = ".jpg";
    static final String[] URLS = {
            BASE + "prior_design_audi_r8_gt850-wide" + EXT,
            BASE + "2015_audi_rs6_avant_exclusive-wide" + EXT,
            BASE + "2015_audi_tt_coupe_quattro-wide" + EXT,
            BASE + "2015_audi_tt_coupe_quattro-wide" + EXT,
            BASE + "2014_audi_prologue_concept_4-wide" + EXT,
            BASE2 + "2010/WP4ce483c6efa9d" + EXT,

    };

    private Data() {
        // No instances.
    }
}
```

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 10):

Picasso library is used only to load the images from network.

You need to address your request with other library such as [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) or any other that support actions on images.

Comment: I've been trying for hours to implement PhotoView in my project but with no succes. It's not that easy as it was for Picasso ( copy the jar. ) and done. Can you help me a little?

Comment: EDIT. I found PhotoView library-1.2.3 and I added it to my project. I'm experimenting with it right now, I keep getting an error when I pinch in the image `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1`

Comment: I know it's an old post, but you can try using https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view

Answer (score 3):

```
PhotoViewAttacher photoViewAttacher;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    Picasso.with(this)
            .load("http://easyway-ev.xyz/images/1.png")
            .into(imageView);//Regular
    photoViewAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(imageView);}
```

this is my answer, I take Picasso, and after i used photoView, also this video how sync photoView [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HETZi6Depz4)
I hope this help you!

Answer (score 2):

Just use TouchImageView instead of ImageView.

https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView